# Store a folder into a single file without using external library or database

Tags: zip, compression, storage, archive

I want to archive and unarchive a whole folder into/from a file. It's similar to compress/uncompress a folder as a zip file. The original folder structure should be preserved.

Here're what I'm trying to do:
-  Archive a whole folder into a single archive file.
-  Unarchive an archive file to a target folder (i.e extract the file onto another folder)
-  Update a file (file content or file name) in the archive file without having to recreate the whole 
archive from scratch.
-  Delete one or many files or folders (and file within them)  from the archive.

It would be much easier if I use external libraries or database for storage. But I need to do those tasks without using any library/tool. Please give me suggestion.

Comment: You can certainly do those things in code with no external libraries, but developing an archiver - such as what you describe - is no trivial task, even without data compression, so what specifically do you need help with?

Comment: So you basically want to reimplement libtar (~4000 lines of code, https://github.com/tklauser/libtar)?